# How to use a webserver installed on a guest machine from the host

Tags: webserver, vmware

I am using VMWare player and I have a webserver installed in my Linux guest machine
(Linux Mint with Tomcat).

I want to access the webserver from my host machine
(Windows 7).

What are the steps required?
Thank you

Comment: How about `http://<ip-of-your-linux-guest>/`

Comment: thanks, how should I find it? running ipconfig /all?

Comment: Only, on the Linux box it is ifconfig.

Comment: Thank you, I made ifconfig on the Linux guest and I am able to reach the webserver using http://<ip-of-your-linux-guest>:8080 (for tomcat). 
Using ipconfig /all on the windows host gave me a bunch of vmware addresses but no one of them was correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your Linux box (the guest), open a terminal, and type:
    ifconfig

Look at the output, you should see a INET ADDR (or something like that) and it will have your ip address beside it. Something like 192.168.7.10 (this is an example).

Then go back to your host, amd in a web browser type in 'http://(the ip you just found)'

This should connect to your webserver

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use the `hostname` command on the guest Linux machine to figure out its name (I think the default is *ubuntu*), then use it from your host -- e.g. `http://(the name you just found)` (in my case, `http://ubuntu/`)